# RegEx: prioritize the length of the match instead of the keyword order

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way to instruct a RegEx to match a string based on the length of the match, rather than the order in which the keywords are listed in the regular expression?

Say I have this string of words:

`word1 word2 word3`

If I run RegEx `(word1|word1 word2|word1 word2 word3)`, it will match `word1`. That's because `word1` is the first keyword listed in the regular expression.

If I run RegEx `(word1 word2 word3|word1 word2|word1)`, then this will match `word1 word2 word3` (for the same reason).

What I need to do, is run the first RegEx, but get the result of the second one.

So basically I need to instruct the regular expression to ignore the keyword order, and prioritize the number of words matched (the length of the match actually). So RegEx `(word1|word1 word2|word1 word2 word3)` should not match `word1` because it's the first one listed, but `word1 word2 word3` because it's the longest match.

Is that possible, please?

Comment: "run the first RegEx, but get the result of the second one" - why can't you run the regex that yields the result you need?

Comment: The only way is to reorder the alternatives in the regex. Just do it.

Comment: To ASDFGerte: that's because I have multiple regular expressions, and each one has hundreds of keywords, in various combinations. As a general rule, I am interested in getting the longest match. Writing the RegEx based on the length of each keyword would not be helpful at all! That's because many times the matches include multiple words, not necessarily a single one. That's what I expect the RegEx to do for me: count the length of each final match and show me the one which is the longest. I am using this with a JavaScript that highlights keywords on web pages.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to make sure word1 is present, then check and capture word2, and then check and capture word3.

If that is correct, you could use `/word1(\sword2(\sword3)?)?/` [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/IsF5wr/1/)

Comment: Sorry, this won't do it, as `word1` is not always present. The same with `word2`, etc.